# Refreshing ADO.NET Entity data model after removing column from table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm trying to figure out a way how to refresh my already mapped .net entity data model.

The thing is, I've removed a specific column from my DB table in SQL and now I'm trying to have the changes reflect to my project as well.. When I try to run it, it says that "GalleryURL" column is missing in the model.

I've tried doing it the "regular" way by doing:

"Update model from database"...

But this doesn't work, my column is still shown in the model for some reason... How can I solve this issue without completely dropping the current model ???

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Go to your EDMX file, right click on the column and delete!

Comment: @Shyju really that easy??? Wait ill try omg ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the entire entity in the .edmx and do an "Update from database". It will recreate the entity.

Comment: Or that as well, removing the specific column did the job as well, but that's it yeah!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Whenever you perform some more complex operations on an entity, you could always delete and recreate the entity.